# How to add dynamic tree and layer in GeoExt

Tags: openlayers, geoext

I am using GeoExt, OpenLayers and GeoServer for map. Now I want to create dynamic tree and layer using GeoExt. So that any user can create a tree and add its layer (child) to that tree dynamically. I have seen many examples on GeoExt website tree panel like http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/tree.html, but this  a static example.

I want it so that a user can add any number of tree and it layer dynamically. It is possible by GeoExt and OpenLayers, If there is any other solution for it please suggest.

How can I do it?

Please help me.